# Can SQL Server 2005 load an XML object and transverse it like in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

i have a stored proc in sql2005 and it makes use of xml functionality in the manor listed below:

```
SELECT
    rr.item.value('@id','varchar(50)') as id,      
    rr.item.value('@name','varchar(50)') as name,      
    rr.item.value('@value','varchar(50)') as value,      
    rr.item.value('@type','varchar(50)') as type      
INTO #tmp      
FROM @xmlInput.nodes('/RWFCriteria/item') as rr(item)
```

the param `@xmlInput` is a XML data type field in the DB that stored various XML chunks of data. i was wondering if i can make my stored proc smarter and use this XML data chunk like i can in .net where i load it into an XML Document object and can transverse nodes, make replacements to attributes, remove nodes, add nodes... within my SQL Code???

is this possible of the SQL uses XML in a much more simplified way and we need to wait for future versions of SQL server to have more feature rich XML abilities?

Note: CLR running in SQL Server is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It is capable of processing XML data (as of version 2000), however it's not like C#, it has all of it's own syntax and operators.

Here's an article that might help you get started: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming/